# Upgrade Mongoid from 4 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a ruby-on-rails app.
And I used Mongoid 4.0 and now updated to 5.0.
When I run below command:

```
rails s
```

but getting error:

```
config/application.rb:56:in `<class:Application>': uninitialized constant AppName::Application::Moped (NameError)
    from config/application.rb:22:in `<module:ModeTokyo>'
    from config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nora/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/nora/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because there is an invalid statement in `config/application.rb`, which does not work since Mongoid 5.

I should change this line:

```
Moped.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

into:

```
Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

This document would be helpful:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#logging